# How to read from a dynamic excel file?

Tags: java, excel, jxl

Values in my dynamic excel file are changing every second, and i would like to read the new values through java. The problem I am facing is that I have to always save the file and then load its values to the program. Is it possible that excel internally saves the file automatically so that I'm loaded with new values every time.

Answer (score 0):

Aman, can you clarify from where your excel sheet being updated dynamically? if you are writing it via another program, then you must use write method in the output stream. then only the values will be persisted

Comment: Hello, I am working on algorithmic trading strategies and the dynamic excel file is updated corresponding to the current price of that stock. I want this my prog. to pick new value every time which will further help me making a dynamic graph, based on changed value. and the question is how can I pick updated values? It will be very tedious if I save it time and time again in order to get new value.

Comment: If the no of stocks you are dealing is bit less, you have to use the main memory for tracking the updated values.Put them in a map. while exiting persist their value in the excel file.

Answer (score 0):

```
Values in my dynamic excel file are changing every second
```

Does this means it is saved in hard drive already or to be saved?
Who is changing the value? You or other application?

Make sure the changes are persisted. Other wise you are reading the same value from HD, not from RAM.

```
Is it possible that excel internally saves the file automatically
```

For this you need to use VBA., which I don't think you need to know.
But you can do that yourself from Java.

Comment: Hello, I am working on algorithmic trading strategies and the dynamic excel file is updated corresponding to the current price of that stock. I want my prog. to pick new value every time which will further help me making a dynamic graph, based on changed value. and the question is how can I pick updated values? It will be very tedious if I save it time and time again in order to get new value. Is VBA my key to it?

Comment: If you are talking about communication between two different systems, it's not an easy thing. You have to decide which system will take the responsibility of maintaining and sending the data. Web Service might also be required.

Comment: If you can access the database from which the values of that excel sheet is coming, it will be easier. Otherwise, the system that change the values of excel sheet itself has to send you the data. Can you see the complication now?

Comment: Yes, since my client side app will be on same computer, so I don't have to deal with communication complications. The problem is I am not able to find any web service or API that can solve my problem, the companies are not very much open in providing there databases either. So I am stuck with this excel file that I want to read from.

Comment: I can't understand how exactly you excel file is being created or generated. What is the location of the excel file? Do you have to download that? This makes it hard to give suggestion.

Comment: company X has provided a software, in that software the price of stocks keep on changing corresponding to the market value. This software also provides an option "copy data". After copying that data, i simply open an excel file and paste it there. It automatically takes care of the rest, I don't know where excel is communicating to now or how it was handled. All I have now is an excel file whose stock prices are changing. Now I want that updated data. I hope this helps. If you have any other suggestions of doing this job any other way, you are welcome!

Answer (score 0):

You keep this excel file in a folder and start a thread that will  monitor the excel file. Means you can poll this excel file and get the latest content in your java code.

Comment: Ok, but the problem I am facing that dynamic file is running in background, price of the stock is dynamic here. Now since the when it updates file, it needs to be saved as the mapping of new and old has not yet been done. How can I possibly do it? Please refer to my reply to another answer to gain some more insight what I am doing. Thank you.